Solve $1 < 2$. Does it make sense to ask this?
I am translating GeoGebra's step-by-step solver (https://www.geogebra.org/solver/en) from English to Brazilian Portuguese.
When asking GeoGebra to solve $1 < 2$, the following explanation is given by the system:

On the other hand, asking to solve $0 \cdot x +1 < 2$ gives:

My question: does it make sense to ask students to solve $1 < 2$? My students would say: Teacher, there is nothing to solve for ... I explain that solve $1 < 2$ means solve $0 \cdot x + 1 < 2$ and, then, they see that any number is a solution of the inequality

I think it does not make sense to say "solve 1<2." If you have your heart set on something like this, at least say "for what values of x is 1<2?"

Why not just clarify your questions, instead of making your students put effort into learning how you want them to parse unclearly-worded questions?

The ordinary meaning of "solving" an equation (or inequality, or system of such) is to determine all the values of the variables that make that equation (or . . .) true. But what are "the variables"? The ordinary meaning is all the variables that occur in the equation (or . . .).
This convention, the ordinary meaning, has the curious consequence that, even though the inequalities $1<2$ and $0\cdot x+1<2$ are equivalent, the ordinary meanings of solving them are different. The second would ask for all values of $x$ that satisfy the inequality, and my answer would be "all real numbers". The first would ask for no information, and my answer would be silence.
The ordinary meanings can be overridden by explicitly saying which variables one should solve for. So "solve for $x$ the inequality $1<2$" would be the same problem as "solve the inequality $0\cdot x+1<2$". But in the absence of such a specification of the variables to solve for, I'd follow the ordinary meanings as above.

Is there any reference that formalizes the concept of solving an inequality? Perhaps a book on logic?

@HumbertoJoséBortolossi You don't need formal references for a common convention that agrees with common sense. The full standard construct for the instruction to solve the relation (inequality, identity, whatever) is Find all values of $x\in A$ such that the predicate $P(x)$ holds true. Here $A$ can be a set of numbers, vectors, apples, monkeys, or anything else and $P$ any predicate. The standard meaning of the solution set is then the set of all elements $x$ of $A\cap D$ for which $P(x)$ takes the "true" value where $D$ is the domain of $P$. That is the formalization of what Andreas wrote

(+1) I saw this question yesterday and wanted to answer, but didn't know how to phrase my concerns. What you've written is pretty much exactly what I was thinking, non-verbally, and I'm glad to see that you've spelled it out much better than I would have. One thing I would have additionally included relates to "But what are "the variables?". Namely, if we're allowed to include an invisible $x,$ why stop there? Why not $0\cdot x + 0 \cdot y + 0 \cdot z + 1 < 2$ (use invisible $x,y,z$ variables) and infinitely many other possibilities?

@fedja, problrem is when the preducate has no variables.

@HumbertoJoséBortolossi It doesn't matter for the formalization I gave. The answer is just $A$ if $P$ is true and $\varnothing$ if it is false. The second case doesn't require the knowledge of the set $A$, but the first one does, so "for what $x$ is $1<2$?" is an ill-posed problem in the sense that the answer "for all $x$" doesn't define a set but only says that the predicate "$\forall x, 1<2$" is true,  but "for what integer $x$ is $1<2$?" has a clear and unambiguous answer $x\in\mathbb Z$.  Often the universe $A$ is implied by the context, but specifying it explicitly is always a good idea.

@fedja, as evidenced by the diverse answers and comments here, I believe the topic lacks proper formalization."

@HumbertoJoséBortolossi The diversity of answers reflects just the glaring ill-posedness of the problem as you posed it (Solve $1<2$). Even "For what $x$ is $1<2$?" is incomplete unless the context around it makes it clear what set of $x$ is considered. Otherwise every answer and comment given so far seems to agree with what I said about the formalization. If you or someone else disagree with this last statement, just indicate the discrepancy :-)


Solve the inequality $1 < 2$

is a poor question. It is not clear how it should be answered.

Is this inequality true or false: $1 < 2$

has the correct answer true.

Solve for $x$ in this inequality: $1 < 2$

has the correct answer this has infinitely many solutions; all values of x are solutions.
Clarifying the question fixes the problem.

Geogebra itself will reword the question if you ask for more practice. This link https://www.geogebra.org/mathpractice/en/practice?expr=1%20%3C%202 (probably will be dead within a year, but it works today) rewords the question to "Determine whether the inequality is true or false." This is good. Unfortunately it then gives two possible answers: "No solution" or "Infinitely many solutions." This is simply wrong. Good luck translating it!

The question could be answered with a good definition of what it means to "solve an inequality." A quality reference presenting and discussing such a definition would suffice. The problem is that such a reference seems hard to find. This reminds me of the famous quote by Arthur Schopenhauer: "So the problem is not so much to see what nobody has yet seen, as to think what nobody has yet thought concerning that which everybody sees."

this seems to be a good reference: https://scholarworks.gvsu.edu/books/23/

'The question could be answered with a good definition of what it means to "solve an inequality."?' No. My entire point is that you will not succeed at defining what it means to "solve an inequality." It is an ill-defined thing to say and you should not say it. You should instead say something precise and well-defined, like "solve this inequality for $x$" or "solve this inequality for $x, y,$ and $z$" or "Is this inequality true or false?"

Your interpretation is wrong. Let's have a look at both inequalities:
First: $1<2$
Second: $0 \cdot x + 1 < 2$
Both inequalities are true.
What does that mean?
Well, simple: you can take every unknown variable inside each of those inequalities, and for every possible value of that variable, the inequality is true.
You: "But the first inequality does not contain a variable???"
I: "So what? Can you tell me a value for $x$ for which the inequality $1<2$ is not true?"
You: "No, I can't."
I: "So: $\forall x : 1 < 2$"
As you see, both inequalities are equal.

@Dominique, that’s a valid point, but I think that thinking in terms of counterexamples might be quite sophisticated for basic school students.
